# Watch all files saved in a folder and make changes to another file via gulp

Tags: javascript, json, gulp, gulp-task

My basic requirement is to look for changes done to any file in `js`,`css` folder and update a JSON file.

---

**Directory structure:**

- html

  - css

    - x.css
    - y.css
  - js

    - a.js
    - b.js
    - c.js
  - server

    - versions.json

**`versions.json`:**

```
{
  "css": {
     "x.css": 1,
     "y.css": 1,
  },
  "js": {
     "a.js": 1,
     "b.js": 1,
     "c.js": 1,
  },
}
```

As I make any changes to any of the files in `js` and `css` folder, I want gulp to return the name of the file that was saved and look for the key in `versions.json` and increase its value by `1` i.e. if I save `a.js` then it should update *only* the value of  `"a.js"` in `versions.json` to `2`.

---

**Here's what I've done:**

```
gulp.task('upgrade-file-version', function() {
  gulp.src('server/versions.json')
    .pipe(modify({
        fileModifier: function(file, contents)
        {
           var fileContent = contents;
           var parsedObj = JSON.parse(fileContent);
           var dir = 'js';   // folder name
           var filename = 'a.js';  // file name
           var oldVersion = parsedObj[dir][filename];
           var newVersion = oldVersion + 1;
           parsedObj[dir][filename] = newVersion;
           var newFileContent = JSON.stringify(parsedObj, null, 4);

           return newFileContent;
        }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('server/'));
});
```

Plugin: [gulp-modify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-modify)

The variables `dir` and `filename` needs to have the value of the folder and name of the changed file.

Any improvement over this or even an another approach is fine

Comment: Why do you want to use Gulp for that? Just rewrite the file with `fs` methods. You can use Gulp to watch for file changes, though.

Comment: @MaxArt What's `fs` methods ?

Comment: I mean [these methods](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). In particular `readFile` and `writeFile`.

Comment: I have no idea of node.js. Can you show how I can use it in the above code?

Comment: How are you even executing Gulp task if you're not using Node.js? Fact is, you are: Node is the underlying environment, with all its built-in APIs. All you need to do is something like `var fs = require('fs');` and then you're ready, use `fs.readFile` and so on. I suggest reading Node's documentation before proceeding, you'll have a much clearer idea.